# What card game was played in "Solo: A Star Wars Story"?

Tags: identify-this-game

*Han Solo* won the *Millennium Falcon* at the end by playing a card game. What game was that actually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The card game is called [Corellian Spike](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Corellian_Spike), a variation of [sabacc](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sabacc).

[image: Cards that are used in the game.]